# Writing three for loops into one line (python)

Tags: python, nested-loops

I have the following program

```
import numpy as np

X = np.asarray([ [2,3,4,5,1,1,1],
  [1,2,3,4,1,1,1],
  [3,3,3,3,1,1,1]])

Nrows=X.shape[0]
Ncols1=X.shape[1]

cols=np.asarray( [[1,3]])
Ncols2=cols.shape[1]

Y = np.ndarray(shape=(Nrows,Ncols2))

for i in range(Nrows):
    for j in range(Ncols2):
        sum=0
        for k in range(Ncols1):
            sum=sum+np.exp(-(X[i,k]-X[i,cols[0,j])**2)
        Y[i,j]=sum
```

I want to reduce the three loops into one line. The motivation here is partially for speedup consideration and partially for practicing python skills.

So I can turn it into two loops by writing it as:

```
for i in range(Nrows):
    for j in range(Ncols1):
        Y[i,j]=np.sum(np.exp(-(X[i,]-X[i,cols[0,j]])**2))
```

And I can turn it into one loop by writing it as:

```
for i in range(Nrows):
   Y[i,]=map(lambda j: np.sum(np.exp(-(X[i,]-X[i,cols[0,j]])**2)),range(Ncols2))
```

But I cannot figure out how to turn this into one line. My instinct is to try

```
Y[:,]=map(lambda j: np.sum(np.exp(-(X[:,]-X[:,cols[0,j]])**2)),range(Ncols2))
```

But this fails with "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,7) (3,)"

Any help would be very much appreciated.

-Nick

Comment: I'm not sure whether or not condensing your for loops into one line would be more efficient or not. But I am sure that you'll end up with a very convoluted mess.

Comment: I agree with what @leaf said

Comment: Don't write codes you cant wont understand. that microoptimization wont help much. bad practice

Comment: In general, _less code_ doesn't necessarily mean _faster code_. Believe it or not, in some cases the opposite holds true.

Comment: if you want to practice your python skills, use it [the way it was intended](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)  "Flat is better than nested.
Sparse is better than dense."

Answer (score 2):

```
Y=np.asarray([np.sum(np.exp(-(X[i,]-X[i, cols[0,j]])**2)) for i in range(Nrows) for j in range(Ncols2)]).reshape((Nrows,Ncols2))

>>> Y
array([[ 1.80902144,  1.38631883],
       [ 2.85771284,  1.38668872],
       [ 4.05494692,  4.05494692]])
```

This uses [list comp](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/) which, pretty much just your for loops on a single line.

```
[np.sum(np.exp(-(X[i,]-X[i, cols[0,j]])**2)) for i in range(Nrows) for j in range(Ncols2)]
```

which is kinda congruent to this:

```
Y=[]
for i in range(Nrows):
  for j in range(Ncols2):
    Y.append(#your big formula that uses i and j as arguments)
```

since its a list, you have to create an array out of it and reshape it to your liking, hence the `np.asarray` before the list comp, and the `.reshape` after

never got to play with numpy too much...i like it!

Comment: thanks for the edits Tadhg! I'll be more professional next time